# Put a div on dark image

Tags: html, image, css

I have this code:

```
<style>
    #container {
        position: relative;
    }
    div.overlay {
        opacity: 0.6;
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
<div style="width:200px; height:200px" id="background" class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Sports_portal_bar_icon.png"width="200px" height="200px" />
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/baweseqo/1/edit.
I want to add a div with text on it.
how can I do that?

Comment: http://www.codeacademy.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do position absolute:

Here is the example http://jsbin.com/nikafamo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

The background image needs to be done in CSS. The text is just put in the div:

CSS:

```
 #container {
position: relative;
}
div.overlay {
opacity: 0.6;
background-color: black;
position: absolute;
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons   
/d/db/Sports_portal_bar_icon.png);
}
 .colortext{
  color:cyan;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="overlay"> 
<p class="colortext">your text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this inside the `<div id="container">`

```
<div>
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
```